# Google SpreadSheet Script - Check number of files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to save 3 SpreadSheets to one. For this I have to check if the 3 files exist. But my code is not working:

```
function mergeSheets() {
    var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('myFolder').next();  
    var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFiles();
    var file1 = "myfile1.xlsx";
    var file2 = "myfile2.xlsx";
    var file3 = "myfile3.xlsx";

    while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
      var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

      if ( (sheet.getName()==file1) && (sheet.getName()==file2) && 
         (sheet.getName()==file3)) {

        var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("myList");      
        var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

        for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {      
           spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
        } 

        // Rename sheets with string "Copy of fileX" to "fileX" 
        if (newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Kopie von file1') == true){
            newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Kopie von file1').setName('file1')
        }

        if (newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Kopie von file2') == true){
          newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Kopie von file2').setName('file2')
        }

        if (newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Kopie file3') == true){
           newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Kopie von file3').setName('file3')
        }

        // Delete standard sheet if create a new spreadsheet
        newSpreadSheet
          .deleteSheet(newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Tabellenblatt1'))

        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadSheet.getId())
        var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('myFolder').next();
        var newFile = folder.addFile(file);
        DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea why this is not working. If I use online one file for the if-statement without AND-operator it works but I think that this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all three files explicitly, excluding all others.  Use the `search()` method:

```
function mergeSheets() {
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('myFolder').next();  
  var spreadSheets,thisFile;

  var file1 = "myfile1.xlsx";
  var file2 = "myfile2.xlsx";
  var file3 = "myfile3.xlsx";

  spreadSheets = myFolder.searchFiles('title contains "' + file1 + 
                '" or title contains "' + file2 + 
                '" or title contains "' + file3 + '"');

  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
    thisFile = spreadSheets.next();

    Logger.log('name: ' + thisFile.getName())

  }

}
```

But I don't think that getting an array of files and looping through them is the best strategy.  If the number of files is always 3, and you know the exact file name, then you might want to get each file separately.

```
var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('myFolder').next();  

var file1 = myFolder.getFilesByName("myfile1.xlsx").next();
var file2 = myFolder.getFilesByName("myfile2.xlsx").next();
var file3 = myFolder.getFilesByName("myfile3.xlsx").next();
```

Comment: By the way what does active sheet mean? Does it mean when I am using a trigger with closed file? Is my active sheet the sheet with filterfunction?

Comment: There is no active sheet if your code is in a stand alone Apps Script file.  That only works if your Apps Script project is bound to a document (Form, Sheet, Doc)  In that case you need to get the spreadsheet file by ID.